# Haskell error: type variable not in scope when defining algebraic data type

Tags: haskell

Why does the error

```
proba.hs:5:28: Not in scope: type variable `<stderr>: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

appear when trying to compile the file proba.hs with the following code:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
    print (isBalanced (Node 17 (Node 14  Empty Empty) (Node 20 (Node 20 Empty Empty) (Node 20 Empty Empty))) 2)

data Tree a = Empty | Node а (Tree a) (Tree a) 
             deriving (Read, Show)

depth :: Tree a -> Int
depth  Empty         = 0
depth (Node _ t1 t2) = 1 + max (depth t1) (depth t2)

isBalanced :: Tree a -> Int -> Bool
isBalanced Empty _          = True
isBalanced (Node n t1 t2) k = abs (depth t1 - depth t2) <= k && isBalanced t1 k && isBalanced t2 k
```

Comment: According to the guidelines, there are *no* urgent questions.

Comment: Ok. Could you help me for my question?

Comment: Is this exactly how the file looks like (indentation as well)?

Comment: Yes, except that print is indented.

Comment: Can you tell us how you are compiling the file?

Comment: With SciTE. Our assistant at university uses it instead of a text editor and ghci prompt.

Comment: Flagging to close as just a typo.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **first two `а`'s** from your `data` declaration aren't [Latin](https://unicode-table.com/en/0061/) (U+0061), they're [Cyrillic](https://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=%D0%B0) (U+0430).

There's nothing wrong with using Cyrillic characters, GHC supports them - but in this line the Latin `a`s don't match the name of the previous type variable Cyrillic `а`.

---

Replacing:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node а (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

With:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

Should fix this (make sure you type all the `a`'s yourself). And maybe check someone's not trying to play a prank on you...

Comment: Chapeau - I wouldn't have spotted that one in a while - esp. since `runghc testfile.hs` yields `testfile.hs:24:20: error: Not in scope: type variable ‘а’`.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I know, right - I just happened to delete the letter when checking the syntax in my editor, and when I re-typed it it worked. Then the error OP quoted ("invalid character") made me think to check the unicode representation. Nice to know that GHC supports unicode though, even if it makes debugging this sort of thing harder!

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! The task is from a partner university in Sofia and I just copy-pasted the given algebraic data type - perhaps they have typed a cyrillic 'a'. I would never have figured it out on my own. Thank you again!